# Error when trying to go to Stack Overflow Chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, error-message

I recently reached 20 reputation points, so I decided to try out Stack Overflow Chat. However when I go to chat.stackoverflow.com, it just shows an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error. There's no kind of error code. I attempted to use a different browser (Chrome instead of Firefox), but the error happened immediately after I signed in.

Comment: Seems OK to me ATM.

Comment: This appears to be related to my account in some way as the site works until I sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed your old chat account, so you should be able to visit chat again (and it'll create a new account at that time).

We also delete chat profiles when Q&A profiles are removed (as of a few months ago), so this should no longer be an issue for any recently deleted profiles.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be due to the fact that you had a previous account, created a chat account with it, then deleted your account. When you recreated your account, the stub of your chat account still existed so now the system is erroring out.

I tried to delete your old chat account, but was blocked. That will require a developer to do. You may want to contact them directly about this.